# Convert dumbquotes to smartquotes in text(), but ignore/retain child elements.

Tags: xml, xslt

I am facing this problem in converting dumbquotes in text() to smartquotes. Here is the template I am using:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string regex="&quot;([^&quot;]*)&quot;" select=".">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
       <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&quot;([^&quot;]*)&quot;' , '“$1”')"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
       <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>                   
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

This works well for content like:

```
<p>“Sachin Tendulkar” is the captain of Mumbai Indians.</p>
```

However, it fails when the `<p>` has inner child nodes. For eg:

```
<p>"Board of control<changedText action="deleted"/><changedText action="added"> for</changedText> Cricket In India" is the national governing body for cricket in India.</p>
```

In such a scenario, text() only contains `"Board of control` in the first instance. As it does not find any closing quotes, the template does not convert it into smartquotes.

Please help me modify this template so that quotes are converted as well as the child nodes are retained.

Comment: This is tough, if you could be sure that a starting quote always stands before a character and a closing quote always stands behind a character you could just match that. So for example something like `(^&quot;.|\s&quot;.)` could match all starting quotes and `(.&quot;$|.&quot;\s)` all end quotes.

Comment: @TobiasKlevenz you are right. I removed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment suggests that you want the first quote mark in each paragraph to become a left smartquote, then alternate right and left quotes through the rest of the paragraph.

So at the start of each text node you need to determine whether there are an even or an odd number of quotes in total across all the text nodes in this paragraph that *precede* this one, in order to know whether you're starting this text node "inside" or "outside" a quotation (i.e. should the next smartquote be a right one or a left one).

```
<xsl:variable name="thisNode" select="." />
<xsl:variable name="inQuotes" select="
      sum(for $text in ancestor::p[1]//text()[. &lt;&lt; $thisNode]
          return string-length(replace($text, '[^&quot;]', ''))) mod 2" />
```

(`ancestor::p[1]//text()[. << $thisNode]` is an XPath expression selecting the text node descendants of the enclosing `p` element that are before the current one in document order)

Once you know this you can use a while-loop-style recursive template to process the current text node

```
<xsl:template name="smartquotes">
  <xsl:param name="q" as="xs:string*"/>
  <xsl:param name="text" as="xs:string" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&quot;')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($text, '&quot;'), $q[1])" />
      <xsl:call-template name="smartquotes">
        <xsl:with-param name="q" select="($q[2], $q[1])" />
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&quot;')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:sequence select="$text" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

passing `.` as the `text` parameter and either `('“','”')` or `('”','“')` for `q` depending on whether you are currently `$inQuotes`.

This looks hopelessly inefficient (a naïve implementation would be quadratic in the number of text nodes) but hopefully an XSLT processor would be able to optimize by cacheing the `string-length(replace($text, '[^&quot;]', ''))` values for each node.

Comment: Thank you, @Ian Roberts. The solution worked perfectly. The only tweak that I needed to do was preceding-sibling::text() instead of preceding::text() while setting the variable value(inQuotes) as I needed to check only the p tag and not throughout the document.

Comment: @Chaitanyabangera that won't necessarily work, e.g. consider `<p>This is "an <changedText action="deleted"/><changedText action="added">important quote"</changedText></p>`, but I've suggested an alternative XPath that will find all the preceding text nodes _within the current paragraph_.

Comment: Thanks again. Made a slight change again. Changed sum(for $text in ancestor::p[1] to sum(for $text in ancestor::*:p[1]
Note: In my limited XSLT experience, I have never seen the usage of "for" and "return" in XSLT. Looks really interesting and powerful.

Comment: @Chaitanyabangera XPath 2.0 is far far more powerful than XPath 1.0, there's all sorts of goodies in there and it's well worth getting to know them.